# Why can LuaJIT/Openresty use deprecated 'arg' language feature?

Tags: lua, luajit, openresty

My understanding is that LuaJIT uses the Lua 5.1 syntax. In Lua 5.1, the 'arg' feature was removed from the language.

However, the following code works.

```
// test.lua
local function foo()
  for k,v in pairs(arg) do
    print(k .. " " .. v)
  end
end

foo()
```

I would expect `arg` to be nil, but it exists and is doing the Lua 5.0 functionality.

Running `resty test.lua hello world` results in:

```
0 test.lua
1 hello
2 world
-1 /usr/local/bin/resty
```

Why does this work? Are there exceptions to the 5.1 syntax that Openresty and LuaJIT can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing two different things.

The `arg` table you see here is not a "deprecated Lua feature". It's a table of arguments given to Lua interpreter, explicitly pushed to the global `arg` variable by the interpreter, and it's still there in the latest Lua and LuaJIT versions.

The feature you've heard was removed - that's about replacing implicit `arg` parameter with vararg expression in vararg functions. I.e. the extra arguments to functions now available through `...` syntax, and not as a table of collected values through implicit `arg` parameter.